# Are Emojis supported in IE-10?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, emoji

I opened following 2 websites in IE-10 and Chrome in Windows-7, but failed to load any emoji.

1. http://copypastecharacter.com/emojis
2. http://getemoji.com/

Searching on internet - found these 2 fixes, but doesn't look like they're working :

1. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2780340
2. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2729094

Any thoughts, guidelines?

Comment: I think emoji support in IE might depend on the version of Windows that you're running.

Comment: Tested from IE8-IE11 (and Edge) on Windows 10 and they show fine. @libertyernie might be right.

Comment: @libertyernie is right.